# Multi dimensional Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Recently I received a copy of javascript code from my colleague, I totally confused with this.  Please give me advice or any reference.

```js
for (p = 0; p < countITEM; p++) {
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].image1[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].image1;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].title[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].title;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].description[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].description;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].unitprice;

  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].avai[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].avai;

  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option1[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option1;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option1_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option1_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option2[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option2;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option2_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option2_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option3[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option3;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option3_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option3_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option4[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option4;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option4_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option4_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option5[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option5;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].option5_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].option5_unitprice;

  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon1[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon1;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon1_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon1_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon2[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon2;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon2_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon2_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon3[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon3;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon3_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon3_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon4[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon4;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon4_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon4_unitprice;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon5[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon5;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].addon5_unitprice[arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM] = arrayITEM[p].addon5_unitprice;

  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].countITEM++;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[arrayITEM[p].category].ptrITEM++;
}
```

Comment: Reference to what? Just ask your colleague. He/She should know best what it is about, other than an object.

Comment: Assigning `arrayCATEGORY_item[ arrayITEM[ p ].category ]` to a variable inside the loop would make the iterations more readable.

Comment: @JavaScript I mean the structure of the array. Any suggested website?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - it is currently impossible to answer since you are not asking a specific question

Comment: Object arrays have protean structures. I doubt any reference is going to have exactly yours in it, except for your internal code documentation, which your colleague should be able to provide. Use `console.log(arrayCATEGORY_item)` to get the structure of the array in the console.

Comment: @Lain I udstd this " arrayCATEGORY_item[ arrayITEM[ p ].category ].image1" is object, but I don't udstd the meaning after this "[ arrayCATEGORY_item[ arrayITEM[ p ].category ].ptrITEM ]"

Comment: That is either an index for an array or a key for an object, depending on what `ptrITEM` is. Since you do a `ptrITEM++` at the bottom of the loop I suspect it being an array. However, it feels like a weird structure since that array gets increasing indices on each loop while the previous object also changes due to `arrayITEM[p].category`. Also it would be better to `push` `options` instead to be limited by predetermined properties like `option1` and `option2`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very compressible

That does not answer your question (What IS your question) but makes it easier to read

```js
countITEM.forEach((item, p) => {
  const aItem = arrayITEM[p];
  const cat = aItem.category;
  const ptrITEM = arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].ptrITEM

  arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].image1[ptrITEM] = aItem.image1;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].title[ptrITEM] = aItem.title;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].description[ptrITEM] = aItem.description;
  arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].unitprice[ptrITEM] = aItem.unitprice;

  arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].avai[ptrITEM] = aItem.avai;

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    arrayCATEGORY_item[cat]["option" + i][ptrITEM] = aItem["option" + i];
    arrayCATEGORY_item[cat]["option" + i + "_unitprice"][ptrITEM] = aItem["option" + i + "_unitprice"];

    arrayCATEGORY_item[cat]["addon" + i][ptrITEM] = aItem["addon" + i];
    arrayCATEGORY_item[cat]["addon" + i + "_unitprice"][ptrITEM] = aItem["addon" + i + "_unitprice"];

    arrayCATEGORY_item[cat].countITEM++;
    ptrITEM++;
  }
})
```